# Loop to find range that number does not equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to write a loop to find out the range when the numbers does not equal to 0.

Let me show you sample data

```
index    Window No.    Fuel Consumption
0        0             0
1        1             100
2        2             101.1
3        3             102.2
4        4             107.5
5        5             0
6        6             0
7        7             100
8        8             110
9        9             107.5
10       10            0
11       11            0
```

As you can see the above sample code, how do I make it return me the ranges where numbers does not equal to 0?

Desired output:

```
Window No. 1 ~ Window No.4
Window No. 7 ~ Window No.9
```

Comment: Try not to use the index column as the index column is actually a datetime64 column!

Comment: Is Window No. always monotonically growing by 1? In that case you only need to loop through the fuel consumption array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
import numpy as np

zero = df['Fuel Consumption'] == 0
nonzero = df['Fuel Consumption'] != 0

# find start indices of all non zero sequences
start = np.flatnonzero(nonzero & zero.shift(fill_value=True))

# find end indices of all non zero sequences
end = np.flatnonzero(nonzero & zero.shift(-1, fill_value=True))

# loop through indices and print Window No.
windows = df['Window No.'].values

for i in range(len(start)):
    ws, we = windows[start[i]], windows[end[i]]
    avg_fuel = df['Fuel Consumption'].iloc[start[i]:end[i]+1].mean()
    print(f'Window No. {ws} ~ Window No. {we} with avg fuel: {avg_fuel:.2f}')

Window No. 1 ~ Window No. 4 with avg fuel: 102.70
Window No. 7 ~ Window No. 9 with avg fuel: 105.83
```

Comment: thanks for this! is it possible to automate calculation of mean Fuel Consumption in each window range?

Comment: Updated with mean fuel consumption. You can basically extract the fuel for each window and calculate mean of it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. But I am met with another problem that shows: IndexError: index 132 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 132. I'm thinking that means my Dataframe is too long for them to print out everything.. is it possible to also then get the  total mean of all the avg fuel? meaning (102.7+105.83)/2 in the solution you provided for me, where 2 is the total count of window range

Comment: Hmm can you check which line is throwing the error ? As for the total mean, do you really want the `(102.7 + 105.83)/2` ? I think you might just want `df['Fuel Consumption'][lambda x: x != 0].mean()` ? i.e. just remove all zeros and then average. If you need average of averages though, you can append the average to a list and then calculate average as `sum(avg_list) / len(avg_list)`.

Comment: thank you the average issue is solved. this line ---> 15     ws, we = windows[start[i]], windows[end[i]]

Comment: Should've fixed. Can you try again ?